# about axios.all(),if I have some likely funs to run,how can i use the Axios.all

Tags: javascript

```
function (type) getMember {
    var that = this;
    var url = "/XXXXX";
    return axios.post(url)
}
axios.all().then(axios.spread(function () {
    console.log('init finished')
}));
```

now  I have to function GetMember of different type,so I choose 
axios.all(),I hope it work,yeah, it can work.

```
axios.all([getMember(0),getMember(1),getMember(2)]).then(axios.spread(
function () {
    console.log('init finished');
    console.log(arguments.length)//3
}));
```

but I think it`s not graceful for coding. I want to write a circulation ,and push arguments into "all(" ")",like this,I try 'eval(str)',it can work and run the function that I want to run,but arguments.length only be one, I can get all the data from all requests.

Answer (score -1):

I found the following method. It is not the best, but it does work:

```
var requestFun = '[';
     for (var i = 0; i < operType.length; i++) {
    requestFun += 'this.getMemberInfo(operType[' + i + ']),';
    }
    requestFun += ']'
    axios.all(eval(requestFun)).then(axios.spread(function () {

})
```